# Periodicity of Markov chains under cartesian product

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Suppose that you have a finite state Markov chain, with $n$ states and characterized by $p_{i,j}$ the probability of reaching state $j$ from state $i$. 
Consider the new Markov chain with $n^2$ states and transition probabilities $$p_{i_1i_2,j_1j_2}=p_{i_2,j_1}p_{j_1,j_2}.$$ Note that, for all $i_a$ and $i_b$, $$p_{i_ai_2,j_1j_2}=p_{i_bi_2,j_1j_2}.$$

Now the idea behind this "product" is to study the periodicity of the new chain. For some trivial examples this transform makes a periodic chain become aperiodic; think of a chain with two states with $p_{1,0}=p_{0,1}=1$. Then my question is:

*Does the iterated application of this "product" render any chain aperiodic?*

I guess there should be some easy counterexample but so far didn't come up with any.

Comment: If the original chain is $X=(X_t)$ the transformed chain is $Y=(Y_t)$ with $Y_t=(X_{2t-1},X_{2t})$. If $X$ has period $3$ then $Y$ still has period $3$. Thus, the iterated application of this transform does not render every chain aperiodic.

Comment: @Did Not sure I follow, if you consider $Y_t=(X_{3t-2},X_{3t-1},X_{3t})$ I would say that the period disappears

Comment: Sorry but I see no reason to consider the process defined by $Y_t=(X_{3t-2},X_{3t-1},X_{3t})$, which seems quite unrelated to the setting described in your question.